# How to substitute x values for legends in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

So, I am trying to build a circular barplot similiar as the one that follows:

```
library(tidyverse)

a <- c("Like", "Dislike", "Neutral")
b <- c("Price", "Functionality", "Functionality: missing pieces", "Durability")
n <- c(10, 0, 5, 6,5,4,19,28,4,6,9,1)

data <- data.frame(a,b,n)

ggplot(data, aes(x=b, y= n, fill = a))+geom_bar(stat="identity")+
ylim(-100, 120)+
coord_polar(start = 0)
```

But I would like to keep it clean and put the names of the bars in a legend box instead of above the bar. Substituting the names for numbers and then linking it to a legend would be ideal.

Answer (score 2):

You could plot them as shapes:

```
data <- data.frame(a, b, n) %>% 
  mutate(b_fct = as.factor(b))

shapes <- data$b_fct %>%
  levels() %>% 
  length() %>% 
  seq() %>% 
  as.character() %>%
  map_int(utf8ToInt)

ggplot(data, aes(x = b_fct, shape = b, y = n, fill = a)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_point(y = 120) +
  ylim(-100, 120) +
  coord_polar(start = 0) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = NULL) +
  scale_shape_manual(values = shapes)
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, I was just looking for that method when you posted your answer. Is there a way to control size of the numbers (labels) without affecting the size of the dots in the `a` legend? (Even better, can those dots be removed?)

Comment: You can remove them try: `+ guides(fill = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape = NA)))`

Answer (score 1):

You could convert `b` to a factor and then abuse `scale_color_manual` a little:

```
a <- c("Like", "Dislike", "Neutral")
b <- factor(c("Price", "Functionality", "Functionality: missing pieces", "Durability"), c("Price", "Functionality", "Functionality: missing pieces", "Durability"), ordered = T)
n <- c(10, 0, 5, 6,5,4,19,28,4,6,9,1)

ggplot(data, aes(x=as.character(as.numeric(b)), y= n, fill = a, color = b))+geom_bar(stat="identity")+
  ylim(-100, 120)+
  coord_polar(start = 0) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  scale_color_manual(
    values = rep('#ffffff00', length(unique(b))), 
    labels = paste(as.numeric(b), as.character(b), sep = ': '), 
    guide = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = '#ffffff'), keywidth = 0))
```

[image: enter]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this, using the caption feature:

```
a <- c("Like", "Dislike", "Neutral")
b <- as.character(seq_len(4))
n <- c(10, 0, 5, 6,5,4,19,28,4,6,9,1)

data <- data.frame(a,b,n)

ggplot(data, aes(x=b, y= n, fill = a))+geom_bar(stat="identity")+
ylim(-100, 120)+
coord_polar(start = 0) +
    labs(caption=paste((paste(seq_len(4), c("Price", "Functionality", "Functionality: missing pieces", "Durability"), sep=": ")), collapse="\n")) +
theme (plot.caption=element_text(hjust=0))
```